# Solving linear programming by python

Tags: python, gekko

I want to solve linear programming with Python. The model is:

```
Maximizing x1 + x2  
S.t:  
    x1 + x2 <=1  
    0<= x1 , x2 <=1
```

So I tried this:

```
from gekko import GEKKO

model = GEKKO(remote=False)
x1 = model.Var(0.2 , lb=0 , ub=1)
x2 = model.Var(0.2 , lb=0 , ub=1)

model.Equation = (sum(x1 , x2) <=1)

model.Maximize(sum(x1 , x2))
```

But I got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8024/1372822120.py in <module>
      6 x2 = model.Var(0.2 , lb=0 , ub=1)
      7 
----> 8 model.Equation = (sum(x1 , x2) <=1)
      9 
     10 model.Maximize(sum(x1 , x2))

~\Anaconda3\envs\Python3.10\lib\site-packages\gekko\gk_variable.py in __getitem__(self, key)
     78         return len(self.value)
     79     def __getitem__(self,key):
---> 80         return self.value[key]
     81     def __setitem__(self,key,value):
     82         self.value[key] = value

~\Anaconda3\envs\Python3.10\lib\site-packages\gekko\gk_operators.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    145 
    146     def __getitem__(self,key):
--> 147         return self.value[key]
    148 
    149     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the entire error message.

Comment: simply change `sum(x1 , x2)` to `x1 + x2`

Comment: [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) takes an iterable and a start argument

Comment: But... the code and error in the traceback is different from what you've shown in the question

Comment: That set of inequalities has an infinite number of solutions.  Not sure what you're expecting from this.

Comment: Your code example uses `sum()`, but your error message says `np.sum()`. Please make sure your code accurately reflects what you are actually doing.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice sorry about it, I was trying using Numpy. edited.

Comment: @TimRoberts Are you familiar with [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming)?

Comment: oic...even maximizing x1+x2 has infinite solutions...

Comment: Here are a few other ways to solve large-scale linear programming problems in dense or sparse matrix form in Gekko: https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/LinearProgramming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment section, simply changing `sum(x1 , x2)` to `x1 + x2` should solve the issue. Also, you should try Solving the `model` with `model.solve()`! so:

```
from gekko import GEKKO

model = GEKKO(remote=False)
x1 = model.Var(0.2 , lb=0 , ub=1)
x2 = model.Var(0.2 , lb=0 , ub=1)

model.Equation = (x1 + x2 <=1)

model.Maximize(x1 + x2)
model.solve()
```

If you want to know about the optimal solution and avoid the complete report of Gekko, you can set `model.solve(disp=False)` and then try:

```
x1[0] , x2[0]
```

this gives me:

```
(1.0, 1.0)
```

Then whereas your objective function is `x1 + x2`, You can get the optimal value of the objective function by:

```
x1[0] + x2[0]
>>> 2.0
```

Comment: Right, there's still a `sum(x1,x2)` in there.

Comment: What result did it produce?  I don't really want to install all of that.

Comment: @TimRoberts I did. Out of curiosity. It gives a very long print out and in the end `The final value of the objective function is  -2.00000001947265`. Have no idea what that means...

Comment: @TimRoberts I'll write about it in continue! Edited.

Comment: But, but, but (1.0,1.0) violates the constraint that x1+x2 <= 1.

Comment: @TimRoberts Great point. I guess the mathematical model should be `ub= 0.9999999`. @fandak, can you please check the model again? Seems your constraints should be `x1<1` and `x2<1`

Comment: That wouldn't matter.  (0.999999,0.999999) also violates the constraint.  (0.1,0.9) works.  (0.2,0.8) works.  (0.5,0.5) works.  Any pair of non-negative reals where x1 = 1-x2 works.